# Is an analytic function equal to its Taylor series at endpoints?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Is a real analytic function equal to its Taylor series at the endpoints of the interval of convergence, provided the series converges a the endpoint? I.e. is a power series continuous at the endpoints of its domain?

Comment: Please look here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbelsConvergenceTheorem.html

Comment: hmm, that looks highly relevant but a little confusing.  So the answer is 
"yes" if its the right endpoint? Very odd.

Answer (score 1):

No. In In the theory of complex analytic functions there is a theorem which say that a singularity is on the convergence circle so, it is impossible to have convergence of the Taylor series at all points of this circle for all analytic functions. This is only the case for some functions.

example:  the function $f(x) = \frac1{1-x}= \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ has a radius of convergence 1. And the function exist at x=-1 but the series diverge at x=-1.

Comment: I'm only asking about the convergence case.

Comment: so this is the Abel's theorem

Comment: So is my interpretation of Abel's theorem correct?:  It's true if its a right endpoint?

Comment: Yes. If $f(x)=\sum_n a_n x^n$ and $\sum_n a_n$ converge, then $\lim_{x \to 1^-} \sum_n a_n x^n = f(1)$

Comment: Thanks! It would be nice to have a left endpoint counter example

Comment: see the example in my answer. Necessary the sum of the $a_n$ diverge in this case.

Comment: I mean an example where the series converges at the left endpoint to something different from the value of f

Comment: It can't.  Abel's theorem applies to any point on the circle of convergence where the series converges.

Comment: @RobertIsrael thanks so much. That answers my question.

Comment: Although I'm puzzled why the wolfram article linked above specifies "positive argument"

Comment: So actually your answer "No" is incorrect. You should change it to "yes" by Abel's theorem.

Comment: @Robert Israel If you're going to talk about "circle of convergence" I assume you are now talking about complex analytic functions. If so, there are more ways to take the limit to a point on the circle than in the real case, and Abel's theorem necessarily has to be limited. The classical statement is that the limit must be taken on a Stolz sector of the disk.

Comment: @MarcelBesixdouze The OP asked about convergence on the real line.  That is in a Stolz sector.